# discord.py | play audio from url

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I want to make my bot playing audio from an url, but I don't want to download the file ...

Here is my code:

```
@commands.command(name='test')
    async def test(self, ctx):

        search = "morpheus tutorials discord bot python"

        if ctx.message.author.voice == None:
            await ctx.send(embed=Embeds.txt("No Voice Channel", "You need to be in a voice channel to use this command!", ctx.author))
            return

        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel

        voice = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.voice_channels, name=channel.name)

        voice_client = discord.utils.get(self.client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

        if voice_client == None:
            await voice.connect()
        else:
            await voice_client.move_to(channel)

        search = search.replace(" ", "+")

        html = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + search)
        video_ids = re.findall(r"watch\?v=(\S{11})", html.read().decode())

        #################################
        await ctx.send("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + video_ids[0])
        # AND HERE SHOULD IT PLAY
        #################################
```

I have tryied create_ytdl_player method, but saw that its no longer supported what can I do?

Comment: You can take a look at one of the examples in the discord.py github repo, [link](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/basic_voice.py)

Comment: I'm trying with the line:

ctx.voice_client.play(url, after=lambda e: print('Player error: %s' % e) if e else None)

But then I get error, need Audio Source not str

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use pafy.

First import some stuff and set FFmpeg options...

```py
import pafy
from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio, PCMVolumeTransformer


FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5','options': '-vn'}
```

Then play it

```py
@commands.command(name='test')
    async def test(self, ctx):

        search = "morpheus tutorials discord bot python"

        if ctx.message.author.voice == None:
            await ctx.send(embed=Embeds.txt("No Voice Channel", "You need to be in a voice channel to use this command!", ctx.author))
            return

        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel

        voice = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.voice_channels, name=channel.name)

        voice_client = discord.utils.get(self.client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

        if voice_client == None:
            voice_client = await voice.connect()
        else:
            await voice_client.move_to(channel)

        search = search.replace(" ", "+")

        html = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + search)
        video_ids = re.findall(r"watch\?v=(\S{11})", html.read().decode())

        
        await ctx.send("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + video_ids[0])

        song = pafy.new(video_ids[0])  # creates a new pafy object

        audio = song.getbestaudio()  # gets an audio source

        source = FFmpegPCMAudio(audio.url, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)  # converts the youtube audio source into a source discord can use

        voice_client.play(source)  # play the source
```

Comment: Please add more explantation to your answer

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake. You need to unpack the FFmpeg Options, I just updatet my answer

Answer (score 1):

If the `source` argument is a `str` it is directly fed as input to `ffmpeg` binary by `FFmpegPCMAudio` internally.
`ffmpeg` supports urls as input out of the box. so you can just pass the url instead of file path.

```
source = FFmpegPCMAudio("https://example.com/demo.mp3", executable="ffmpeg")
ctx.voice_client.play(source, after=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `bot` with `client` if you need to. Then, try this out:

```
import asyncio

import discord
import youtube_dl

from discord.ext import commands

# Suppress noise about console usage from errors
youtube_dl.utils.bug_reports_message = lambda: ''


ytdl_format_options = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'outtmpl': '%(extractor)s-%(id)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s',
    'restrictfilenames': True,
    'noplaylist': True,
    'nocheckcertificate': True,
    'ignoreerrors': False,
    'logtostderr': False,
    'quiet': True,
    'no_warnings': True,
    'default_search': 'auto',
    'source_address': '0.0.0.0' # bind to ipv4 since ipv6 addresses cause issues sometimes
}

ffmpeg_options = {
    'options': '-vn'
}

ytdl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ytdl_format_options)


class YTDLSource(discord.PCMVolumeTransformer):
    def __init__(self, source, *, data, volume=0.5):
        super().__init__(source, volume)

        self.data = data

        self.title = data.get('title')
        self.url = data.get('url')

    @classmethod
    async def from_url(cls, url, *, loop=None, stream=False):
        loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()
        data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(url, download=not stream))

        if 'entries' in data:
            # take first item from a playlist
            data = data['entries'][0]

        filename = data['url'] if stream else ytdl.prepare_filename(data)
        return cls(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(filename, **ffmpeg_options), data=data)


class Music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command(description="joins a voice channel")
    async def join(self, ctx):
        if ctx.author.voice is None or ctx.author.voice.channel is None:
            return await ctx.send('You need to be in a voice channel to use this command!')

        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            vc = await voice_channel.connect()
        else:
            await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)
            vc = ctx.voice_client

    @commands.command(description="streams music")
    async def play(self, ctx, *, url):
        async with ctx.typing():
            player = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=self.bot.loop, stream=True)
            ctx.voice_client.play(player, after=lambda e: print('Player error: %s' % e) if e else None)
        await ctx.send('Now playing: {}'.format(player.title))
    
    @commands.command(description="stops and disconnects the bot from voice")
    async def leave(self, ctx):
        await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

    @play.before_invoke
    async def ensure_voice(self, ctx):
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            if ctx.author.voice:
                await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()
            else:
                await ctx.send("You are not connected to a voice channel.")
                raise commands.CommandError("Author not connected to a voice channel.")
        elif ctx.voice_client.is_playing():
            ctx.voice_client.stop()

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Music(bot))
```

Not only will this play from URL, but it will also play from the name of the video itself.