# I'm having an issue with my discord bot playing audio from a youtube url

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord, discord.py

```
sync def hog():
channel = bot.get_channel(964971002289356893)
url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GyRmkAfpCOM'
await asyncio.sleep(1)
voice_channel = bot.get_channel(int(964971002289356893))
vc = await voice_channel.connect()
#vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('C:/Users/alexa/Downloads/hogrider.mp3'))
vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(source='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GyRmkAfpCOM', executable='ffmpeg.exe'))
while vc.is_playing():
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
await vc.disconnect()
```

It works fine with the audio file from my laptop, but I want to play it from a youtube link.
It gives me an error:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GyRmkAfpCOM: Invalid data found when processing input

Thank you in advance

Comment: I believe you can't directly set a YouTube url as a source here. Try the method suggested in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66116633/3730626

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should change your code to this, but make sure you need to install `ffmpeg`. I'm using this code for my music player (on my discord bot)

```
async def hog(ctx, url:str):
   channel = bot.get_channel(put your channel here)
   vc = ctx,.voice_client
   await asyncio.sleep(1)
   video = search(query=title)
   source = video['formats'][0]['url']
   vc.play(FFmpegPCMAudio(source, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS))
```

as you can see there is `search` function being called.

```
def search(query):
YDL_OPTION = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'noplaylist': True,
    'nocheckcertificate': True,
    'default_search': 'auto',
    'geo_bypass': True,
}

with YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTION) as ydl:
    try:
        requests.get(query)
    except:
        info = ydl.extract_info(f"ytsearch:{query}", download=False)['entries'][0]
    else:
        info = ydl.extract_info(query, download=False)
return info
```