# Discord.py bot joins voice channel but when using voicechannel.play i get error:Command raised an exception: ClientException: Not connected to voice

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord, discord.py

So i've managed to get my discord bot to join a voice channel but when i use the play command it gives me an error that its not conencted to voice `Command raised an exception: ClientException: Not connected to voice.`

Here is my code:

```
import discord
import random
import glob
from discord.ext import commands

##discord intents 
intents = discord.Intents()
intents.members = True
intents.messages = True
intents.guilds = True
intents.voice_states = True
```

connect the bot to a voice channel:

```
    
##called when user wants bot to join voice channel
@bot.command(name ='join', help = 'Make the bot join a voice channel')
async def join(context):
    
    botVoice = context.message.guild.voice_client
    if context.guild.voice_client:
        botvoicechannel = context.message.guild.voice_client.channel
    else:
        botvoicechannel = None
    authorVoice = context.author.voice
    if context.author.voice:
        authorvoicechannel = context.author.voice.channel
    else:
        authorvoicechannel = None
    
    ##await context.reply('bot voice channel: {}\n\nbot voice:\n{}\n\nauthor voice channel: {}\n\nauthor voice voice:\n{}\n\n'.format(botvoicechannel, botVoice, authorvoicechannel, authorVoice))
    
    if not authorVoice and not botVoice:
        await context.reply('Connect to a voice channel first.')
        return
    elif authorVoice and not botVoice:
        await context.reply('Connecting to {}'.format(authorvoicechannel))
        await authorvoicechannel.connect()
        return
    elif not authorVoice and botVoice:
        await context.reply("You aren't in a channel, I'm in {}".format(botvoicechannel))
        return
    elif authorVoice and botVoice:
        if (botvoicechannel == authorvoicechannel):
            await context.reply("I'm already in here.")
            return
        else:
            await context.reply('Moving to you!')
            await botVoice.move_to(authorvoicechannel)
            return
        return
```

and have it play a url:

```
@bot.command(name ='play', help = 'Make the bot play a url')
async def play(context, url):
    botVoice = context.message.guild.voice_client
    audioSource = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(url, executable="ffmpeg")
    botVoice.play(audioSource, after = None)
```

the code works and the bot joins the voice channel. i see it in the voice channel with me, however i get an error when it gets to `botVoice.play(audioSource, after = None)`

the error message is:
`error: Command raised an exception: ClientException: Not connected to voice.`

i changed `botVoice = context.message.guild.voice_client` from `botVoice = context.guild.voice_client` but that didnt seem to change anything. not sure what to try next. It seems like it wants to play the url the bot just doesnt realize its in the voice channel with me.

maybe a related error. if i kill my python script the bot remains in the channel even though its not running. then when i start it up and do the !join command it says its joining even though its already in the channel with me. its weird because on the join command it checks to see if its already in a voice channel so it should know that its in there with me. idk what to try next. thanks for any suggestions. i only posted relevant code. let me know if you think im missing something else.

thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error as you: update your Discord.py. In my case I was on 2.1.0, with 2.2.3 your code works perfectly. To do that, just type in your command executor `pip install --upgrade discord.py`.

If I'm not wrong, that behaviour was not normal and was a bug. You could also notice that `await channel.connect()` would block any code under it. Now you can put your connect code in the same function as the play code, if you desire.

Comment: How did you get it to work? you got no errors when upgrading? You solved my problem! thanks. But now i get errors using ffmpeg.                                                           [in#0 @ 0000010ff35da500] Error opening input: Invalid data found when processing input  [2023-05-26 15:40:35] [INFO    ] discord.voice_client: Voice handshake complete. Endpoint found us-south5730.discord.media                              and                                             
[2023-05-26 15:42:52] [INFO    ] discord.player: ffmpeg process 37080 successfully terminated with return code of 1.

Comment: Could you give me the url you are using?

Comment: Because when I use a mp3 link on my computer, it wourks wonderfully, but when I use a link like a youtube video i get an error just like yours

Comment: Check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66115216/discord-py-play-audio-from-url

Answer (score 0):

When runnning your your bot, you may see that discord.py is giving you this warning:

```
2023-05-22 10:01:35 WARNING  discord.ext.commands.bot Privileged message content intent is missing, commands may not work as expected.
```

this is most probably why the bot does not know that it is in voice. When I ran your bot with the intents you gave it no command would run as the bot didn't have the priviliged message content intent.

Try running you bot with `intents = discord.Intents.all()` and see if the problem persists.

Comment: i tried that. i still get the same error. in fact. I've never seen the warning message that you mentioned. the bot responds to all commands i send it. i just get an error with the play command. it may not work for you because i didn't put the line @bot.command(name ='join') above the async function

Comment: How do you initialize the bot? When I run your exact code with adding only `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)` and `bot.run("The_Token")` it does not work, the bot does not respond to commands. Can you show how do you do it? If it works for you there must be something else. Also, when running your bot with `intents = discord.Intents.all()` I don't get the error that you get, instead the ffmpeg process just terminates instantly and the audio still does not play but I don't have any errors.

Comment: Also, from my knowledge, you need youtube-dl to work with ffmpeg for playing youtube links.